# How can I get a list of Azure DevOps Artifact consumers?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Is there a way in Azure DevOps that I can get a list of people who are using my published artifacts?

Comment: As far as I know, via portal, you only can see how many users have downloaded your artifact. Probably there is some way to do it via API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to get a list of people who are using the published artifacts. You may submit a user voice at website below, product team will evaluate it carefully:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21